# Access VBA code that delete records not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

hi guys i tried that code on access vba and it giving me error
here is it :

```
Private Sub Command102_Click()
If msgbox("are u sure", MsgBoxStyle.yesno, "Delete") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
 Resume
    msgbox ("deleted")
    Else
    msgbox ("canceld")
End If
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
End Sub
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Are you using `VB.NET` or `VBA`? `VBA` does not have such a thing as `MsgBoxStyle` AFAIK. You can do `vbYesNo` instead.

Comment: thank for your fast replay 
i am new at vb btw i just got that  code from internet but i can understand it by the way all i need code doing msgbox by yes or no if yes resume the code if no cancel and the code about delete record that all i hope you understand me  and thx again

Comment: and about the vba i am using the vba with access 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VBA` does not understand this code because it is written for `VB.NET`. If it is the first time you hear about `VB.NET`, think of it as an extension of `VBA` (this is a huge oversimplification and I hope I dont get downvoted because of writing such stuff :) ).

In `VBA` syntax you would do something like:

```
Private Sub Command102_Click()
    If MsgBox(Prompt:="Are you sure?", Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Delete") = vbYes Then
         On Error Resume Next
         DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
         If Err.Number = 0 Then
            MsgBox Prompt:="Deleted", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Deleted"
        Else
            MsgBox Prompt:="There is no record to delete!", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Error"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox Prompt:="Canceled", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Canceled"
    End If
End Sub
```

You do not need `Resume` in this context.

Have a look at [this post](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=76087) as well, it is quite similar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks very much u tried it but i give me error (agruments not optional)

Comment: Sorry, was a bit careless :) Now it works. Any `MsgBox` needs at least a Prompt. By the way, if you try to delete the record but there is no record, you will get an error.. I am adding a message that informs the user in case this happens

Comment: Glad that it helped! If this answer replies 100% to your issue, I suggest you mark it as "accepted" (by clicking on the tick button to the left of the answer's title). This way people who have the same issue will resolve it fast. Also, it is good practice if the question title is a little more descriptive, such as **Access VBA code that delete records not working**. You may want to edit it, so people who google stuff life "Access VBA delete records" get directed here. All the best!